# symfony 2 how to display the error after login with custom authentication handler

Tags: authentication, symfony

I have created an authentication handler and everything is working fine when the user authenticates with success...but when there is a failure I don't know how to return the failure error to my form and display it.

```
public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
}
```

How should my function look like because I do not know how to pass $exception and redirect back to my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to display a message to the user.
You can display a flash message and redirect the user.

```
$request->getSession()->setFlash('error', $exception->getMessage());
```

If you look at the FosUserBundle they display a message direcly in the template

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php

Hope it's helpful

Best regard